# C++ - Problems with pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a code in c++ and i don't understand the meaning of this line:

```
 X = R[i] & X;
```

X and R are both vectors.
I know that the operator `&` returns the address of the vector `X` but i don't understand the correlation with `R[i]`.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends upon the context. `operator &` might have been overloaded.

Comment: In this case the operator `&` is use for the bitwise and

Comment: When you say that both `X` and `R` are vectors, do you mean [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes

Comment: Then how does it compile? There is no standard overload of the bitwise AND operator for the standard vector class.

Comment: There is no standard one but someone could specialise it for the T that it is a vector of

Answer (score 4):

In this case, & is the binary bitwise AND operator.

More on it here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Answer (score 3):

You're right that, as a unary operator, `&` takes the address of its operand.

However, here it's a binary operator: the "bitwise and" operator. The result is the value obtained by setting each bit that's set in both its operands. It can also be written as `bitand` if you prefer obscure words to obscure symbols.

There's also a corresponding assignment operator; the code could be written equivalently as

```
X &= R[i];
```

NOTE: This answer is assuming that `X` is an integer type. However, you say it's a "vector"; in that case, there must be an overload of `operator &` defined for that type, and that will be used here. Presumably, it's not the standard vector type, since that doesn't have such an overload.

Comment: There is no guarantee that such an operator was overloaded. Might be useful to do so though as it would be more optimal

Comment: @CashCow: If `X` isn't an integer type, and the code compiles, then the operator must have been overloaded.

Comment: No, they must have overloaded operator&. But that doesn't mean you can do &=, which needs to be overloaded separately.

Comment: @CashCow: Sorry, looks like my language wasn't clear enough. By "This is assuming..." I meant "The answer is assuming...", not "The side comment about an assignment operator is assuming...". I'll try to clarify it, in case it confuses others.

Answer (score 1):

It would work if somebody overloaded the operator like this:

```
std::vector< T > operator &( T t, std::vector< T > const& vec );
```

for whatever T or they defined a template for all T.

Whoever implemented that might want to implement `operator &=` too which would modify the vector in the same way and avoid copying, but the presence of one does not automatically generate the other.